# Right control key mapped as multi-key in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, keyboard

I am using Ubuntu 9.10 on a Dell D620 Laptop. My laptop's right control key doesn't respond in applications like FireFox, Terminal, and Vim. I can left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and open up new tabs, left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in Vim to switch windows, etc. but not with the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

I ran `xev` in terminal to see if the key press events show up, and they do. This is the output

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xfd, subw 0x0, time 2987783, (160,-9), root:(163,39),
    state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xff20, Multi_key), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xfd, subw 0x0, time 2987852, (160,-9), root:(163,39),
    state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xff20, Multi_key), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

How can I get my right control key to respond again? If there's a shortcut or something that is hogging the functionality of my right control key, how do I clear it? I've set the keyboard layout to default, but that hasn't helped either.

---

Update

In xev, the left control shows up like this

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xfd, subw 0x0, time 3301139, (218,3), root:(221,51),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xfd, subw 0x0, time 3301230, (218,3), root:(221,51),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

It says `Control_L` on the 3rd lines. But for the right control key, it's labeled as `Multi_key`. So it appears my right control key is mapped as the "Multi key", which is probably wrong.

---

I followed the instructions of the first answer and remapped the right control key, and now the right control key shows up as Control_R, but it's still not functioning correctly.

Answer (score 3):

How about remapping it with xmodmap?

```
$xmodmap -e 'keycode 105 = Control_R'
```

Comment: xev now shows that it is mapped to Control_R, but it's still not functioning correctly.

Comment: well, thats an issue of the software than, for the apps the right control key is now 'Control_R'.

Comment: maybe it needs to be added to controls also: `xmodmap -e "add control = Control_R"` like in [this case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684540/how-can-i-have-the-right-ctrl-key-behave-as-the-left-ctrl-key)